# How to expand obs. count using stat_bin as a line to each variable plotted in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram, bar-chart

Consider the following toy data

```
dat=data.frame(value=runif(3000,1,5),
            name=rep(c('A','B','C','D','E','F')),
            code=c(rep('game1',1500),rep('game2',1500))
            )
```

I am visualising it as a stacked histogram using 'identity' from geom_histogram

```
ggplot(dat,aes(x=value))+
    geom_histogram(position='identity',binwidth=0.5,aes(fill=name))+
    theme_bw()+
    scale_fill_brewer(palette="RdBu")+
    facet_wrap(~code)+stat_bin(aes(label=..count..),binwidth=0.5, geom="line", size=1,color='white')
```

How to add the number of observations (count) per variable (name) plotted as a line using stat (..count..). So, essentially 6 lines, one for each condition accross the whole plot (both facets), which will reflect how many observations are there in each bin per variable.

The idea came because the lower bars gets hidden behind the higher ones, so line overlayed would show where the bar ends plus alpha transparency acts not that great in these cases.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for lines for each bin/variable combination? If so, have you tried looking at geom_freqpoly()?

```
ggplot(dat,aes(x=value))+
 geom_histogram(position="identity",binwidth=0.5,aes(fill=name))+
 theme_bw()+
 scale_fill_brewer(palette="RdBu")+
 facet_wrap(~code)+geom_freqpoly(binwidth=0.5,aes(colour=name),size=1)
```

See [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BeMkN.png) for an example:

You can play around with the line sizing, but I think it still looks cluttered. You might try doing a geom_bar as well. Something like:

```
ggplot(dat,aes(x=value)) +
 geom_bar(position="dodge",binwidth=0.5,aes(fill=name))+
 theme_bw()+
 scale_fill_brewer(palette="RdBu")+
 facet_wrap(~code)
```

Might be helpful. You can play around with the spacing between the bars/bins as well.

Comment: Great, `geom_freqpoly` is what I needed. Actually, now I have ended up removing all the bars and plot the same data using `geom_density`, looks much cleaner and sorts my purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a `geom_density()` seems to do the trick:

```
+ geom_density(aes(value, ..count.., color=name))
```